# What is a good MFC C++ GUI architecture for multiple similar window arrangements

Tags: mfc

I am considering a rewrite of an MFC Dialog application I wrote over a decade ago. I originally chose a Dialog application type because in general the user clicks control inputs and the application provides real-time data from hardware via USB and displays the data in edit boxes. The app also writes information to a file. Since the user never does any file editing I didn't see a need for SDI or MDI application type.

I've now learned that the SDI application type along with CFormView provides some interesting advantages such as scrolling, window resizing:
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?267664-MFC-Dialog-How-to-enhance-a-dialog-based-application-with-Menu-Toolbar

The reason for my rewrite is that my application is un-maintainable and doesn't scale well. Originally I created a CDialog for each type of "screen" that I show but lots of code is common among the various screens. In fact over time I started reusing CDialog classes and with the use of state variables simply hid, renamed, or repositioned many of the controls to make the screen look appropriate in the context of the application.

I tried deriving the CDialog classes from a common base class but I didn't achieve great code reuse this way. I also found that I had common resources that I was constantly passing around to the various windows which just added unnecessary overhead.

As the application evolved it also became difficult to keep track of the state of the application (for processing USB hardware data input, user input, button enabling etc). Using a hierarchical statechart as the basis for my application might clean this up.

Should I consider putting a superset of ALL the necessary controls on ONE CFormView and simply hiding, renaming, and repositioning controls from the very beginning and using a statechart to manage this?

All the examples I see put the code directly in the input control handlers but maybe I should use the handlers to change state and then let the state machine do the decision-making to reduce this spaghetti code.

So my primary questions are:
1. Would SDI would buy me anything for writing and reading files (such as reporting and logging) if the user does not perform editing?
2. Does CFormView make sense?
3. Does it make sense to put all controls on one CFormView instead of multiple classes and Dialog resources?
4. Have you tried using a state machine in MFC such as Boost Statechart or Miro Samek's Quantum Leaps?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html
http://www.state-machine.com/products/index.html

Comment: Rewrites hardly ever end well, especially so, if the author isn't familiar with the designated framework (scrolling a view is in no way related to the application type, for example). What does help is properly structuring your application. Take a piece of paper and document the current state, and contrive a proposed architecture. UML is helpful, but not strictly necessary. Don't touch the code, until you have a clear vision of where things should be going. Judging from your questions, you don't even have a clear understanding of the problem your application is trying to solve.

Comment: I agree on the importance of understanding and documenting the project requirements. I wrote and maintained this app which has been very successful with my customers for 14 years. In addition to writing software I have other responsibilities in the company so unfortunately haven't had the time to refactor as the project has grown and features were added. It's often easier to spot opportunities for improvement in hindsight. I'm hoping some experienced MFC developers could offer some insight on my questions. CFormView does appear to make scrolling (where needed) A LOT easier than with CDialog.